# How can I ask Riak 1.4 to index and then be able to search my document based on properties of embedded document?

Tags: riak, riak-search

Working with Riak 1.4.7

I have a document that has a property that is an array of embedded documents. Here is a sample of the document:

```
{"prospect":true, "name":"HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ",
"contact_email":"contact@HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ.gr",
"e_shops":[{"store_url":"www.store.url.com","display_name":"hello there"},
           {"store_url":"www.store2.url.com","display_name":"hello2 there"}]
}
```

The corresponding bucket has index enabled and works fine. For example, the following search command locate the object without problem:

```
search-cmd search index_name contact_email:contact@HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ.gr
```

The question here is how can I search by the `store_url` for example.

`store_url` is a property of an embedded document which, in turn, is an element of an array property of the main document.

1) Do I have to specify a custom schema file in order for the index to index these properties?

2) Do I have to query using some kind of special syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default JSON extractor should handle that case by joining all of the values in the array in a space separated list.  Nested names are handled by joining them with an underscore.  So in this case, the field `e_shops_store_url` would contain `www.store.url.com www.store2.url.com`.  You can query that field normally.

I ran a quick example to demonstrate:

```
root@node1:~# search-cmd install searchtest

 :: Installing Riak Search <--> KV hook on bucket 'searchtest'.
root@node1:~# curl 172.31.0.1:8098/buckets/searchtest/keys/test1 \
-XPUT -H"content-type:application/json" \
-d '{"prospect":true, "name":"HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ",
> "contact_email":"contact@HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ.gr",
> "e_shops":[{"store_url":"www.store.url.com","display_name":"hello there"},
>            {"store_url":"www.store2.url.com","display_name":"hello2 there"}]
> }'
root@node1:~# curl 172.31.0.1:8098/buckets/searchtest/keys/test2 \
-XPUT -H"content-type:application/json" \
-d '{"prospect":true, "name":"-HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ",
>"contact_email":"contact@-HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ.gr",
>"e_shops":[{"store_url":"www.store.url.com","display_name":"hello there"},
>           {"store_url":"www.store3.url.com","display_name":"hello3 there"}]
>}'
root@node1:~# search-cmd search-doc searchtest e_shops_store_url:www.store.url.com

 :: Searching for 'e_shops_store_url:www.store.url.com' / '' in searchtest...

------------------------------

index/id: searchtest/test1
<<"contact_email">> => <<"contact@HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ.gr">>
<<"e_shops_display_name">> => <<"hello there hello2 there">>
<<"e_shops_store_url">> => <<"www.store.url.com www.store2.url.com">>
<<"name">> => <<"HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ">>
<<"prospect">> => <<"true">>

------------------------------

index/id: searchtest/test2
<<"contact_email">> => <<"contact@-HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ.gr">>
<<"e_shops_display_name">> => <<"hello there hello3 there">>
<<"e_shops_store_url">> => <<"www.store.url.com www.store3.url.com">>
<<"name">> => <<"-HzNUeioPYynsGdXL6iSFvQ">>
<<"prospect">> => <<"true">>

------------------------------

 :: Found 2 results.
 :: Maximum score "0.353553".
```